# MySQL Join query for credit balance

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create mysql query to get balance `(sum(col1)-Sum(col2))` from one table along with name of that userid from another table.

```
-------
table: user
--------
name userid
Kashif Mehmood U001
Kamran Ahmad33 U004
Junaid Akram U006
-------

table: taccbalance, 
--------
userid amountin amountout
U001  5000.00 NULL
U001 NULL 1000.00
U001 10000.00 NULL
U001 NULL 9000.00
U002 10000.00 NULL
U002 NULL 9000.00
U002 5000.00 NULL
U002 NULL 3000.00
-----------------------
```

query to get balance is

```
SELECT userid, SUM(amountin)-SUM(amountout) AS balance
FROM taccbalance
GROUP BY userid;
```

However If I make join with it,it doesnt work

```
SELECT a.name, b.userid, b.balance
FROM user AS a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT userid, SUM(amountin)-SUM(amountout) AS balance
     FROM taccbalance GROUP BY userid) AS b
ON a.userid = b.userid;
```

It just return only one row, rather it should return multiple rows.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you tell us what the row that gets returned looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using left  join

```
    SELECT a.name, b.userid, b.balance
    FROM user AS a
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT userid, SUM(amountin)-SUM(amountout) AS balance
         FROM taccbalance 
         GROUP BY userid
    ) AS b ON a.userid = b.userid;
```

and check for user U002 you have not this value in user table